# Getting values from a hashmap

Tags: java, android

i have the following set of codes.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> listPermissions = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.permdisabled);

    AppData appData = (AppData) getApplicationContext();
    packageInfo = appData.getPackageInfo();

    findViewsById();
    setValues();
    privacy();
}

private void findViewsById() {
    appLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appplabel);
    packageName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.packagee_name);
    req_permission = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.req_permissionn);
    diss_perission = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diss_permissionn);
    label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.suggestionlabel);
    suggest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.suggestion);
}

private void setValues()
{
    // APP name
    appLabel.setText(getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(packageInfo.applicationInfo));

    // package name

    packageName.setText(packageInfo.packageName);

    // uses-permission
    if (packageInfo.requestedPermissions != null) {
        req_permission.setText(getPermissions(packageInfo.requestedPermissions));
        pass = req_permission.toString();
    }
    else {
        req_permission.setText("-");
    }


}

private String getPermissions(String[] requestedPermissions) {
    String permission = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
        permission = permission + requestedPermissions[i] + ",\n";

        boolean check = listPermissions.containsValue(permission);
        if (check == false)
        {
            listPermissions.put(i, permission);
        }

    }
    return permission;
}
```

The problem starts here

```
private void privacy()
{
    diss_perission.setText(listPermissions.get(5));
}
```

The problem is, every time I run this I get the permission listing from 0 - 5 instead of the permission at position 5. pls help.

here is a picture of the result
[Application Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkif4.png)

Comment: can you please elaborate this line : *The problem is, every time I run this I get the permission listing from 0 - 5 instead of the permission at position 5.*

Comment: whenever this code is compiled, diss_perission.setText(listPermissions.get(5)); i get a string listof elements 0-5 from the Hashmap instead of the string value at the position 5

Comment: Of course you get that. You are using the same `permissions` string variable and just concatenating to the end of it. Walk through `getPermissions()` step by step and see what I mean.

Comment: thanks. how do you suggest i write the codes in getPermissions()

Comment: You should not be assigning listPermissions.put(i, permission) because "permission" is a String that accumulates each of the individual permission String values together. Instead, you should be populating like this: listPermissions.put(i, requestedPermissions[i]) since that is the single permission item at that index. This means that your check prior to populating listPermissions should be "boolean check = listPermissions.contains(requestedPermissions[i]). @Joel is exactly right.

Comment: Thanks.. working on it

Comment: HashMap stores "a" key-value pair. For your implementation, use an ArrayList instead. Cause, I do not see a point where you need a HashMap mapping the index with its value. That can be done with an array list too. And, use an Array instead if your permission list will not grow dynamically during the operation of the app.